# Java - HttpUrlConnection returns cached response every time

Tags: java, http, caching, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to gather statistical data from Roblox's currency exchange for analysis. Therefore, I need up-to-date data instead of a cached result. However, it seems that no matter what I do, the result is still cached. It seems that the most intuitive option, `setUseCaches()`, had no effect, and setting the header manually as `Cache-Control: no-cache` does not seem to work either. I inspected the Cache header using Fiddler2 and saw that its value was `Cache-Control: max-age=0`, but it didn't seem to change the program's behavior either. Here are the relevant pieces of code:

URL:

```
private final static String URL = "http://www.roblox.com/my/money.aspx#/#TradeCurrency_tab";
```

GET Request:

```
    URLConnection socket = new URL( URL ).openConnection( );
    socket.setUseCaches( false );
    socket.setDefaultUseCaches( false );
    HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpURLConnection )socket;
    conn.setUseCaches( false );
    conn.setDefaultUseCaches( false );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Pragma",  "no-cache" );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Expires",  "0" );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Cookie", ".ROBLOSECURITY=" + ROBLOSECURITY );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8" );
    conn.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36" );
    conn.setDoInput( true );
    conn.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
    conn.connect();

    Scanner data = new Scanner( conn.getInputStream() );
    data.useDelimiter( "\\A" );
    String result = data.next();

    data.close( );
    conn.disconnect();
```

It may or may not be important to note that it returns a unique result every time I restart the program but not during program runtime.

**Update:**

Wireshark analysis (I tweaked my code a bit since last time ):

```
GET /my/money.aspx HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Cookie: .ROBLOSECURITY=_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|*sensitive*
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: www.roblox.com
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: rbx-ip=; domain=roblox.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: RBXSource=rbx_acquisition_time=1/4/2016 12:45:21 AM&rbx_acquisition_referrer=&rbx_medium=Direct&rbx_source=&rbx_campaign=&rbx_adgroup=&rbx_keyword=&rbx_matchtype=&rbx_send_info=0; domain=roblox.com; expires=Wed, 03-Feb-2016 06:45:21 GMT; path=/
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: rbx-ip=; domain=roblox.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: RBXSource=rbx_acquisition_time=1/4/2016 12:45:21 AM&rbx_acquisition_referrer=&rbx_medium=Direct&rbx_source=&rbx_campaign=&rbx_adgroup=&rbx_keyword=&rbx_matchtype=&rbx_send_info=1; domain=roblox.com; expires=Wed, 03-Feb-2016 06:45:21 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: RBXEventTrackerV2=CreateDate=1/4/2016 12:45:21 AM&rbxid=59210735&browserid=3940274345; domain=roblox.com; expires=Fri, 22-May-2043 05:45:21 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: GuestData=UserID=-856460986; domain=.roblox.com; expires=Fri, 22-May-2043 05:45:21 GMT; path=/
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Date: Mon, 04 Jan 2016 06:45:20 GMT
Content-Length: 153751
```

Comment: Is there a proxy between you and the internet? I've had problems because of proxy cache before.

Comment: Can you add one log for whireshark with correct data and second with incorrect for comparation?

Comment: Wireshark dump of one request/response cycle of the communication is not enough. We need at least two of those. Also, is wireshark running on the client host?

Comment: Hi did you ever get a solution for this, I've been facing the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

If the caching occurs server-side, append a cachebuster to the URL.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpURLConnection )new URL( URL + "?_=" + System.currentTimeMillis() ).openConnection( );
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm starting to believe it's just a java bug and I'm going to have to look alternative means.

Comment: The URL has a page anchor (#). Suffixing "?" after the URL will not work. It has to be added after ".aspx"

Comment: Link should be like: http://www.roblox.com/my/money.aspx?time=1452336350229#/#TradeCurrency_tab

Answer (score 3):

I notice you are not telling the local `HttpURLConnection` to bypass *its own* caches.

`HttpURLConnection` inherits the method `setUseCaches(boolean)` from `URLConnection`.  From the [Javadoc for `setUseCaches(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setUseCaches-boolean-)

> Sets the value of the useCaches field of this URLConnection to the specified value.
>
> Some protocols do caching of documents. Occasionally, it is important to be able to "tunnel through" and ignore the caches (e.g., the "reload" button in a browser). If the UseCaches flag on a connection is true, the connection is allowed to use whatever caches it can. If false, caches are to be ignored. The default value comes from DefaultUseCaches, which defaults to true.

Comment: I've tried using that method to no avail. And from what I understand, it's the same as using "Cache-Control: no-cache".

Comment: Have you used Wireshark to determine if your system is sending the request out?  If not, the problem is in your client. It would be interesting to see the traffic that is being exchanged, both the first time and subsequently.

Comment: So what happens the second time?

Comment: They're all the same after that.

Comment: Are you going through a proxy? Is the _content_ also identical (i.e. incorrect) in the Wireshark trace? Can you run a network capture at the server?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you have tried most of the cache settings. It could be that it is not your client, but their service that causes this to happen. I can see from your wireshark info that you have "Connection Keep-Alive". Perhaps you could try and set that to "Connection Close" since you say that every time you restart your program you get a non-cached result.

This may not be ideal in a production setting but perhaps it could give you some insight as to what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I missing context (how the given piece of code invoked multiple times) to pin down the problem accurately, but it could be due to reusing the `socket` object instead of instantiating a new one for each request.

Once the connection is open, the `useCache` setting won't matter. Have a look at the implementation of `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection#connect`:

```
protected void plainConnect()  throws IOException {
  if (connected) {
        return;         
  }
  // try to see if request can be served from local cache
  if (cacheHandler != null && getUseCaches()) {
  // ..
}
```

If the connection was opened, it will return immediatly and reuse the existing `InputStream` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
If-Modified-Since: Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do the following operation on your URL before opening your `URLConnection` socket :

```java
URLConnection socket = new URL( URL.replaceFirst("#", "?cacheFrom=" + System.currentTimeMillis()+"#") ).openConnection( );
```